# Which Namecoin block was the first one to be generated by merged mining?

Tags: namecoin, history, merged-mining

For a definitive record is it possible to determine if a namecoin block was generated via merged mining?  Is so which was the first one.

Which is the first bitcoin block to have namecoin information in coinbase transaction?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, block 19200 was mined using MM, by slush's pool. AFAIK first Bitcoin block with merged-mining information was 00000000000002c727047296ee20b628599031c6ea5c09292513fddbb11d34df (block [148557](http://blockexplorer.com/b/148557)), also mined by slush's pool.

Answer (score 1):

NMC block 19200 was the first block to have merged mining hashing on it, Though I don't know if a merged mining pool found this block.
In merged mining, your submitted shares are passed to bitcoin to check if it solves a block. Then it is passed to namecoin. Each are independent of one another. If you find a NMC block, it's just that! No BTC are generated!